# Dynamic Page Height Assign

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

i have to create one asp.net mvc page that will show template of controls.
Controls will be get from xml file.My problem is there hasn't exact number of controls,
so,i need dynamic page height.Our site background is blue color and show page is white.
When i write controls to page,if there has many controls,those are overlap on blue color background.
i already assigned "height:85%","height:auto",however,it doesn't change.My css file is like this.

```
#main-content 
{
 padding:0px 0px 25px; 
 width:747px;
 position:relative;
 -moz-border-radius:6px;
 -webkit-border-radius:6px;
 height:85%;
}
```

Html File is Like Below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="ctl00_Head1">
<link href="../Content/customize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body> 
    <div id="main-content">          
 <div>
    <div style='left:20px;top:80px; position:absolute;' >Name</div>
    <div style='left:80px;top:80px; position:absolute;' ><input id='Text1' type='text' value='Mr.Temp'/></div>
    <div style='left:20px;top:210px; position:absolute;' ><input id='Chk1' type='checkbox' value='Check One' checked/>Check One</div>
    <div style= 'left:20px;top:340px; position:absolute;' ><input id='Radio1' type='radio' value='OptionOne' />OptionOne</div>
    <div style='left:260px;top:80px; position:absolute;' ><image id='image1'/></div>
    <div style= 'left:118px;top:340px; position:absolute;' ><input id='Radio1' type='radio' value='OptionTwo' checked/>OptionTwo</div>
    <table border='1' style='width:400px;'><caption>TempTable</caption>
    <tr align='left' valign='top'>
    <th align='left' valign='top'>Name</th>
    <th align='left' valign='top'>Age</th>
    <th align='left' valign='top'>Address</th></tr>
    <tr align='left' valign='top'>
        <td align='left' valign='top'>Mr.A</td><td align='left' valign='top'>30</td><td align='left' valign='top'>TownshipA</td></tr>
    <tr align='left' valign='top'>
        <td align='left' valign='top'>Mr.B</td><td align='left' valign='top'>40</td><td align='left' valign='top'>TownshipB</td>
    </tr><tr align='left' valign='top'>
        <td align='left' valign='top'>Mr.C</td><td align='left' valign='top'>50</td><td align='left' valign='top'>TownshipC</td></tr>
 </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

please give me right way with some examples.

regards
Indi

Comment: Can we see the relevant HTML as well?

Comment: yes,you can,i post it.thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your absolute positioning.

Absolutely positioned elements don't pad the body with any height.